# Recursive method not returning to previous line position in caller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to find a solution to this for some time. I have found questions and answers on recursion but nothing that seemed to fit this particular situation.

I have written a class which should go through the given folder and all subfolders and rename files and folders if a particular search pattern is found.

Everything works as expected the replaceAllInDir gets called, it replaces files and folders if needed. The next step then is to do the same for all subfolders within the given folder.
So a subfolder gets identified and replaceAllInDir gets called from within itself. Let's assum the particular subfolder called does not contain any subfolders. I would then expect that we return to the parent folder and continue looking for other subfolders. But instead control is not returned to the parent calling method and the program ends.

I am aware of other ways of solving the actual use case, but I cannot explain the behaviour of ruby.

```
class MultiFileAndFolderRename
  attr_accessor :rootDir, :searchPattern, :replacePattern

  def initialize(rootDir, searchPattern, replacePattern)
    @rootDir = rootDir
    @searchPattern = searchPattern
    @replacePattern = replacePattern
  end

  def execute
    replaceAllInDir(@rootDir)
  end

  def getValidDirEntries(dir)
    dirList = Dir.entries(dir)
    dirList.delete('.')
    dirList.delete('..')
    dirList
  end

  def replaceAllInDir(currentDir)
    Dir.chdir(currentDir)
    puts "Processing directory: " + Dir.pwd
    dirList = getValidDirEntries(currentDir)
    dirList.each { |dirEntry|
      attemptRename(dirEntry)
    }

    dirList = getValidDirEntries(currentDir)
    dirList.each { |dirEntry|
      if File.directory?(dirEntry)
        newDir = currentDir + '\\' + dirEntry
        rntemp = MultiFileAndFolderRename.new(newDir, 'searchString', 'replaceString')
        rntemp.replaceAllInDir(newDir)
      end
    }
  end

  def attemptRename(dirEntry)
    if dirEntry.match(@searchPattern)
      newname = dirEntry.to_s.sub(@searchPattern, @replacePattern)
      FileUtils.mv(dirEntry.to_s, newname)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your logic looks ok to me (although your ruby coding conventions are less than normal ;)).  Have you tried outputting the paths to the directories it should theoretically be recursing into?  Is it possible it's seeing the names of directories that have since been renamed (due to some sort of caching) and therefore `File.directory?` never returns true when iterating the `dirlist` for the second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug. The first line of `replaceAllInDir()` is `Dir.chdir()`. `chdir()` changes the directory of the current process on a global scale. It's not call-stack dependent. So later when you move into a subdirectory and change into that, the change becomes permanent even if you return from the recursion.

You need to change back to the correct directory after any call to `replaceAllInDir()`. For example:

```
...
dirList.each { |dirEntry|
  if File.directory?(dirEntry)
    ....
    rntemp.replaceAllInDir(newDir)
    Dir.chdir(currentDir) # <- Restore us back to the correct directory
  end
}
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code, and I have found numerous errors in it. Perhaps if you fix them, your idea is working.

1. You should include in a library like that a part at the end that allows to call it from the shell: `MultiFileAndFolderRename.new(ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2]).execute if __FILE__ == $0` This ensures when you call the ruby code from the shell by `ruby rename.rb test old new`, your class will be instantiated, and the search and replace pattern will be set accordingly.
2. You shouldn't set the current directory, because that ensures that the line `getValidDirEntries(currentDir)` will not work. If you eg. call it for the directory test, and then change your current directory to test, inside the directory, `getValidDirEntries('test')` will not work like expected.
3. You should use only forward slashes instead of the double backward ones. So your code will work on Linux and Mac OS X as well.
4. When you instantiate the new instance of `MultiFileAndFolderRename` (which is not necessary), the arguments to the initializer are the wrong ones. Instead, you should use your current instance and just call `self.replaceAllInDir(newDir)` instead of `rntemp = MultiFileAndFolderRename.new(newDir, 'searchString', 'replaceString');rntemp.replaceAllInDir(newDir)`.

I think the wrong instantiation is the major reason why it works not as expected, but the others should be fixed as well.

Comment: I have taken all the comments on board. And you are right the fix for the problem was in there. Thank you very much for the detail and time taken in answering this.

Comment: How about giving me an up-thumb for that :-)